# Ionic 3: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[{"EmpMenage_Nom":" Joumaa","EmpMenage_Prenom":"Michoto"}]'

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to get user information from web API as JSON, I know this is not an array and that ngfor can't read string but I don't know how to convert it to JSON!!

my provider:

```
getUsers() {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get('http://localhost:57527/api/EmployeMenageApi/GetListEmployeMenage')
    .subscribe(data => {
    resolve(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

}

my ts:

```
export class LoginPage {
lang: any;
users: any = [];
items: any;
allData: any[];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public alertCtrl: 
AlertController, public menuCtrl: MenuController, public employeprovider: EmployeMenageProvider) {
this.getUsers();
}

getUsers() {
 this.employeprovider.getUsers()
  .then(data => {
    this.users = data;

    this.allData = JSON.parse(this.users);
    console.log(this.allData);

  });
  }
```

my HTML:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let user of allData">
  <ion-thumbnail item-left style="size: 1px">
    <img src="{{users.EmpMenage_Photo}}">
  </ion-thumbnail>
  <ion-label>{{users.EmpMenage_Nom}}</ion-label>
```

Comment: Just use: `this.allData.push(this.users);` Donot use JSON.parse()

Comment: I have a new error now "Error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" 
If I do "allData: any=[];" I get the same old error

Comment: Replace `allData: any[];` with `allData: any[] = [];`

Comment: `console.log(this.allData);`?

Comment: Have you tried: `allData: any[] = [];`

Comment: In your original code just remove that `JSON.parse();` and use `this.allData = this.users;` and then try jst let know

Comment: Now i have this
Runtime error
Error: Error trying to diff '[object]'.Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: console.log(this.allData)?

Comment: [{"EmpMenage_Nom":" Joumaa","EmpMenage_Prenom":"Michael","EmpMenage_Photo":null,"EmpMenage_Pin":"","Site_Id":0}]

Comment: The problem is in login.htm
LoginPage.html:14 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[{"EmpMenage_Nom":" Joumaa","EmpMenage_Prenom":"Michael","EmpMenage_Photo":null,"EmpMenage_Pin":"","Site_Id":0}

Comment: can you provide a demo?

Comment: Because it confusing now! I bet there must be a small mistake

Comment: As you can see the project uses local DB and web API, so it will be impossible to put it online.

Comment: Then 1) What is the result of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: [{"EmpMenage_Nom":"2019","EmpMenage_Prenom":"HNCC","EmpMenage_Photo":null,"EmpMenage_Pin":"","Site_Id":0}] this is my console user

i changed my API to get only one user so this can be easyer to follow

Comment: this is my ts code
 getUsers() {
    this.employeprovider.getUsers()
      .then(data => {
        this.users = data;
        this.allData = this.users;
        console.log(data,"this is my console user");

      });
  }

Comment: Thank you very much i solved this in C#

Comment: okay its good then